# Adding Interest Rates to bank accounts in c#

Tags: c#, console, console-application, onlinebanking

Im new to c# and I've created three accounts for a banking system which are: Everyday, Investment, and Omni. The problem I have is that I cant work out how i will be able to add the Interest rates and fees to the accounts in the class. Below is the requirements for each class:

Everyday Account: No interest, no overdraft, no fees

Investment: Interest rates (varied) paid on all funds, no overdraft allowed, fee incurred for failed transaction.

Omni: Interest rates paid only on balances over $1000; specifies overdraft permitted; fee for failed transactions.

Any help with adding this into my classes and code will be much appreciated. Just really stuck at the moment.

// Everyday Account

```
    class Everyday : Account
    {
        //field

        private double minBalance;
        private double maxBalance;


        //properties
        public double MinBalance
        { get { return this.minBalance; } }

        public double MaxBalance
        { get { return this.maxBalance; } }

        //constructors

        public Everyday(double balance) : base()
        {
            this.minBalance = 0;
            this.maxBalance = 1000000000000;
            this.balance = balance;
            accountType = "Everyday Account";
        }

        //methods
    }
```

// Investment Account

```
    class Investment : Account
    {
        //field

        private double minBalance;
        private double maxBalance;


        //properties
        public double MinBalance
        { get { return this.minBalance; } }

        public double MaxBalance
        { get { return this.maxBalance; } }

        //constructors

        public Investment(double balance) : base()
        {
            this.minBalance = 0;
            this.maxBalance = 1000000000000;
            this.balance = balance;
            accountType = "Investment Account";
        }

        //methods
    }
```

// Omni Account

```
    class Omni : Account
    {
        //field

        private double minBalance;
        private double maxBalance;


        //properties
        public double MinBalance
        { get { return this.minBalance; } }

        public double MaxBalance
        { get { return this.maxBalance; } }

        //constructors

        public Omni(double balance) : base()
        {
            this.minBalance = 0;
            this.maxBalance = 1000000000000;
            this.balance = balance;
            accountType = "Omni Account";
        }

        //methods
    }
```

// Account

```
       class Account : Customer
       {

        // Fields

        private double accountNumber;
        protected string accountType;

        protected double balance;
        protected double deposit;
        protected double withdrawal;

        // Properties

        public string AccountType
        {
            get { return this.accountType; }
        }

        public double Withdrawal
        {
            get { return this.withdrawal; }
            set { this.withdrawal = value; }
        }
        public double Deposit
        {
            get { return this.deposit; }
            set { this.deposit = value; }
        }
        public double AcctNumber
        { get { return this.accountNumber; } }

        public double Bal
        { get { return this.balance; } }


        // Creating Random Account Number

        public virtual double AccountNumb()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            this.accountNumber = rand.Next(100000000, 1000000000);
            return accountNumber;
        }


        //Computes General Balance(resets values)
        public virtual double Balance()
        {
            balance = balance + deposit - withdrawal;
            deposit = 0;
            withdrawal = 0;
            return balance;
        }

        //Computers Balance when withdrawal equals zero
        public virtual double DepositBalance(double input)
        {
            deposit = input;
            withdrawal = 0;
            balance = balance + deposit - withdrawal;
            return balance;
        }

        //Computers balance when deposit equals zero
        public virtual double WithBalance(double input)
        {
            withdrawal = input;
            deposit = 0;
            balance = balance + deposit - withdrawal;
            return balance;
        }


        //displays online banking menu
        public virtual void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to your online bank account\nPlease choose from the options below: ");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1.View Client Info");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("2. View Account Balance:");
            Console.WriteLine("     2A.Everyday\n     2B.Investment\n     2C.Omni");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Deposit Funds:\n     3A.Everyday\n     3B.Investment\n     3C.Omni");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("4.Withdraw Funds:\n     4A.Everyday\n     4B.Investment\n     4C.Omni");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("5.Exit");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Perhaps make an interface for accounts' interest rate which you can implement for every type of account based on the functionality you need.

Comment: Unfortunately for this one I have to do it fully using just the console, with no interface.

Comment: I don't mean UI, I mean this - [Interfaces in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces#:~:text=An%20interface%20has%20the%20following%20properties%3A%201%20In,class%20or%20struct%20can%20implement%20multiple%20interfaces.%20)

Comment: Oh ok not sure how I would do that with the interest rates unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

in Investment Class :`
class Investment : Account
{
//field

```
    private double minBalance;
    private double maxBalance;
    //add this
    private double tax;


    //properties
    public double MinBalance
    { get { return this.minBalance; } }

    public double MaxBalance
    { get { return this.maxBalance; } }
    public double Tax{get{return this.tax;}}

    //constructors

    public Investment(double balance) : base()
    {
        this.minBalance = 0;
        this.maxBalance = 1000000000000;
        this.balance = balance*Tax+balance;
        accountType = "Investment Account";
    }

    //methods
}
```

`and in omni class:`
class Omni : Account
{
//field

```
    private double minBalance;
    private double maxBalance;
    private double Tax;


    //properties
    public double MinBalance
    { get { return this.minBalance; } }

    public double MaxBalance
    { get { return this.maxBalance; } }

    public double Tax{get{return this.tax;}}
    //constructors

    public Omni(double balance) : base()
    {
        this.minBalance = 0;
        this.maxBalance = 1000000000000;
        if (balance>=1000){this.balance=blance*Tax+balance}
        else {this.balance=balance}
        accountType = "Omni Account";
    }

    //methods
}
```

`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: add Tax properties in each class that contain on tax , in constructor edit balance to increment /decrement tax ..this based on your project